# convert char`s in string to vector<bool> in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, bit

I have a string

```
std::string line="AGGTAATTCTATTAGAAAAATGGTGTATGTATTTTTACTTACTAATGCAAAGTTTAACAATTACCACTTCATGTATTAAAAGATACTAAC";
```

and i want to convert this string into vector such that

```
A=>00
C=>01
T=>10
G=>11
```

Each char will be denoted as 2 bits, so size of vector would double the string length.

Is there an efficient way of doing this? Most trivial solution is like this :

```
void convert2vec(std::string& str)
{
   std::vector<bool> bits;
   int size= str.length();
   for(int i=0;i<size;++i)
   {
       switch(str[i]){
       case 'A':
        bits.push_back(0); // A = 00
        bits.push_back(0);
        break;
       case 'C':  //C =  01
        bits.push_back(0);
        bits.push_back(1);
        break;
       case 'T': // T = 10
        bits.push_back(1);
        bits.push_back(0);
        break;
       case 'G': //G=11
        bits.push_back(1);
        bits.push_back(1);
        break;
    default:
        cout<<"error";
    }
}
for (auto ch:bits)
{
    cout<<ch;
}
}
```

Comment: Is this necessary? you won't save any space by doing so

Comment: @Quest vector<bool> is implemented in special way which will leads to save space .. I guess

Comment: Can you write a function that appends two bits to a `vector<bool>`? Can you make it choose two bits based on the value of a `char`? Can you call `reserve` to set the vector to the correct size?

Comment: A vector bool already stores bits, not bytes. So the vector bool will be smaller. You could still use a bitset if you know the size at compiletime instead.

Comment: reserve the output vector to twice the length of the input vector; loop (of choice) over the input string calling push_back twice for each input character.  ie about 5 lines of code.  please show your attempt SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: @josefx - bitset is fixed-size though.

Comment: @Useless Remembered it quick enough to do an edit :)

Comment: @HumamHelfawi in that case you won't be able to save 2bit number into a bool.. I'd go ahead and use bitset.

Comment: @Quest i think he wants to add two entries to the vector per char

Comment: bitset size can not be set at runtime , unfortunately. The size of the string can be changed, so I thought i would choose vector<bool>.

Comment: Does linearly looping over the string and building the `vector<bool>` count as efficient? If not you could use a view adapter that holds the string and sort of behaves like a `vector<bool>` in constant time instead.

Comment: vector<byte> also sound good to me.

Comment: `vector<char>` can be faster in some cases due to more complicated indexing operations. If `vector<bool>` fits in cache it can be faster so measure it yourself

Comment: What's the typical length of `line`?

Comment: isn't that a coding for genes of some sort?

Comment: line length can change, it s read from file , it can either be 90 or 100.

Comment: There's specific data structures and libraries for genetic information. (I know https://github.com/bigdatagenomics/adam for example)

Comment: What do you want to optimize? Runtime, memory or does another library require that format?

Comment: the main idea is kmer counting. I have implemented a hash map <string,count>. This string is actually a substring of length L in the line. This map holds lots of space in memory because there are millions of lines in the file. So i want to zip the string part into a more compact form like in bit vector.

Comment: If the strings used in map<string, count> are all the same length and substrings of original_string: Then you could just store the index, where the substring starts, thus using a map<int, count>
(Which would use even less memory than map<vector<bool>, count>)
(If the substrings are not the same length you could save index and length in a long: map<long, count>)

Comment: I'm not sure you gain anything using a vector<bool>. sizeof(bool) returns the same as sizeof(char) on my machine: 1, for one byte. And using two bool to code a char, you get two bytes for one. You could group 4 bases in a char using masks and shift and put these in a vector<char>, to divide size by 4. I think this is what you want to achieve.

Comment: @spacm It can be more space efficient: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool

Comment: Considere use `bitset` instead of vector. The only inconvenient that i see is you must declare it with a constant size like `bitset<128>` before you use it.